# Input Type IDbTransaction

Tags: c#

first of all, I apologize if my question is very basic but I'm just starting in this world.
I have a method:

```
public static byte [] GetVitoria (IDbTransaction trans)
{
   bla bla bla
}
```

how do I create a variable of type IDbTransaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IDbTransaction` is an [Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx).  An Interface is simply a structure of how an object should look or behave.  You want the concrete implementation of the Interface.

The database object that you create will handle your transaction.  And creates a concrete implementation of `IDbTransaction` for you.  [Here is some example code:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbtransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
SqlTransaction transaction;

// Start a local transaction.
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");
```

EDIT:

If you are trying to pass a variable to this method.  It needs to be of **type** `IDbTransaction`.

So you might call your method like this:

```
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");
var bytes = GetVitoria(transaction);
```

Comment: @Unow here at Stackoverflow we show our thanks by upvotes and marking answers. :) Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your database connection object will provide that for you:

```
SqlTransaction myTransaction = myDbConnection.BeginTransaction();
```